# Predicting via Lowess in R (OR reconciling Loess & Lowess)

Tags: r, interpolation, predict, loess, extrapolation

I'm trying to interpolate/locally extrapolate some salary data to fill out a data set.

Here's the data set and a plot of the available data:

```
    experience   salary
 1:          1 21878.67
 2:          2 23401.33
 3:          3 23705.00
 4:          4 24260.00
 5:          5 25758.60
 6:          6 26763.40
 7:          7 27920.00
 8:          8 28600.00
 9:          9 28820.00
10:         10 32600.00
11:         12 30650.00
12:         14 32600.00
13:         15 32600.00
14:         16 37700.00
15:         17 33380.00
16:         20 36784.33
17:         23 35600.00
18:         25 33590.00
19:         30 32600.00
20:         31 33920.00
21:         35 32600.00
```

[image: A scatterplot of the data given above in tabular form, titled "Experience vs. Salary", with an x-axis labelled "Experience" varying from 0 to 35 and a y-axis labelled "$" with labels at 25,000, 30,000, and 35,000. The points are essentially in a bilinear shape -- increasing steadily from 0 to about 20 years, and plateauing after that.]

Given the clear nonlinearity, I'm hoping to interpolate & extrapolate (I want to fill in experience for years 0 through 40) via a local linear estimator, so I defaulted to `lowess`, which gives this:

[image: A plot with the same title, axes, and scatterplot points as above, with a red line superimposed giving the fit from the lowess function, which generally follows the data well.]

This is nice on the plot, but the raw data is missing -- R's plotting device has filled in the blanks for us. I haven't been able to find a `predict` method for this function, as it seems `R` is moving towards using `loess`, which as I understand is a generalization.

However, when I use `loess` (setting `surface="direct"` to be able to extrapolate, as mentioned in `?loess`), which has a standard `predict` method, the fit is less satisfactory:

[image: Another plot with the same baseline data, this time showing a blue line superimposed showing the fit from the loess function; this fit is in a U shape, increasing first before decreasing after around 20 Years]

(There are strong theoretical reasons to say that salary should be non-decreasing--there is some noise/possible mis-measurement driving the U shape here)

And I can't seem to be able to fiddle around with any of the parameters to get back the non-decreasing fit given by `lowess`.

Any suggestions for what to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how to "reconcile" those two functions but I have used the `cobs` package (COnstrained B-Splines Nonparametric Regression Quantiles ) with some success for similar tasks. The default quantile is the (local) median or 0.5 quantile. In this dataset the default choices for span or kernel width seem very appropriate.

```
require(cobs)
Loading required package: cobs
Package cobs (1.3-0) attached.  To cite, see citation("cobs")

 Rbs <- cobs(x=dat$experience,y=dat$salary, constraint= "increase")
qbsks2():
# Performing general knot selection ...
#
# Deleting unnecessary knots ...
 Rbs
#COBS regression spline (degree = 2) from call:
#    cobs(x = dat$experience, y = dat$salary, constraint = "increase")
#{tau=0.5}-quantile;  dimensionality of fit: 5 from {5}
#x$knots[1:4]:  0.999966,  5.000000, 15.000000, 35.000034
plot(Rbs, lwd = 2.5)
```

[image]

It does have a predict method although you will need to use idiosyncratic arguments since it doesn't support the usual `data=` formalism:

```
 help(predict.cobs)
 predict(Rbs, z=seq(0,40,by=5))
       z      fit
 [1,]  0 21519.83
 [2,]  5 25488.71
 [3,] 10 30653.44
 [4,] 15 32773.21
 [5,] 20 33295.84
 [6,] 25 33669.14
 [7,] 30 33893.12
 [8,] 35 33967.78
 [9,] 40 33893.12
```

Comment: awesome! how does one find out about all of these interpolation methods, i'm left to wonder...

Comment: In this case it was by working through the vignette that comes with Roger Koenker's `quantreg`-package.